# CSS Selector for incremented ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of incremented elements

```
<ul>
  <li id="idTab1">
  <li id="idTab2">
  <li id="multiTab1">
  <li id="multiTab2">
  <li id="multiTab3">
  <li id="idTab3">
</ul>
```

Is there some CSS selector method for me to select all 'multiTab' elements? something like 'li #multiTab*' ? :P

Comment: you could do some awful mix of `[id^=startofid]` and `nth-of-type` or something but you're really abusing id's here - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`^=`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp), example:

```
li[id^="mulitiTab"]
```